# how to retrieve json data in table view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

I don't know how to retrieve particular data from this JSON data and insert in tableview.

```
{
"error": "ok",
"data": [{
    "facebook_id": "1068644546541665",
    "user_id": "95590e92-6c74-44d1-9e5c-5a10c6341ba3",
    "name": "Sunil",
    "trackingallowed": 1,
    "trackingpermission": 1
}, {
    "facebook_id": "10311905002886663",
    "user_id": "95ab5fc0-9c6d-4e3e-9cb2-bfa4d53e640f",
    "name": "Saravanan",
    "trackingallowed": 1,
    "trackingpermission": 1
}, {
    "facebook_id": "998936463528828",
    "user_id": "cd6e3c89-bc2d-45a9-8436-9603e1b4724b",
    "name": "Suresh",
    "trackingallowed": 1,
    "trackingpermission": 1
}]
```

}

Getting the values through List array.

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
 [friendsconnection_data appendData:data];
    NSError *localerror;
    NSDictionary *parsedobject =[NSJSONSerialization   JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localerror];
    NSLog(@"parsedobject1 %@",parsedobject);
    ListArray = [parsedobject valueForKey:@"data"];

    NSLog(@"rrresults1 %lu",(unsigned long)ListArray.count);
    NSLog(@"results1 %@",ListArray );   
}
```

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I need to know how to get particular data from JSON. e.g. I want to get only `facebookid` and `name`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self FriendsData];
    static NSString *TableIdentifier =@"tableitem";
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[ListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    tableView.rowHeight = 300;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is that function work in cellforrowatindexpath?

Comment: Which line is causing the crash? What is the `FriendsData` method and why is it called from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Unrelated but why do you set the table view's `rowHeight` every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called?

Comment: May be, `JSONObjectWithData:` method causes error because loading is not completed. You should deserialize data in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` .

Comment: remove `[self FriendsData];` and try

Comment: i removed it . i got bad_access- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    
         return [ListArray count];

Comment: what exactly is `ListArray`? How are you initializing it?

Comment: @UditiS NSMutableArray. ListArray is initialized in  connectiondidFinishLoading

Comment: when i check with breakpoint Listarray inside NSurlconnctiondelegate shows 3 objects.while in tableview list array is empty

Comment: are you able to get jason value ..?

Answer (score -2):

plz use this code. I think it help you

```
NSError *json_parse_error;
NSDictionary *responseDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&json_parse_error];
NSArray *user_info_array=[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"data"];
```

in your table view delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *TableIdentifier=@"tableitem";;
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[user_info_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[user_info_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"facebook_id"];

    return cell;
}
```

//set height for table view cell

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 300.0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Do not use `valueForKey:` to get an object from a dictionary. Use `objectForKey:`. 2) Do not implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` if every row is the same height. Simply set `self.tableView.rowHeight = 300;` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: More importantly, how does this answer solve the crash? Don't just post code as an answer. Explain what the problem was and how your answer fixes the problem.

Comment: yeah table view row height can be set in viewDidLoad

Comment: the problem is setting row height in cellForRowAtIndexPath